# Is it possible to Migrate Live VMs from a Windows 2012 Hyper-V Cluster to a different 2012 R2 Cluster?

Tags: hyper-v, failovercluster, hyper-v-server-2012, hypervisor, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

At the moment I'm in a bit of dilemma because I know that Windows 2012 supports "Shared Nothing Live Migration" but recently I got to know that this feature is available for stand alone Hyper-V Servers. My Setup is that I have 3 Servers running Windows Server 2012 Hyper-v Failover Cluster and I need to migrate everything to a new cluster running on Windows Server 2012 R2 and offcourse some VMs can't be turned off during migration so I need to do this live during production hours. Another note is that both clusters will be running on the different LUNs since each cluster has its own CSVs. I need to know if it is possible to migrate such VMs/Roles Live without have any downtime of the VMs/Roles?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but one exception - live migration works only on "compatible cpu's". There actually is a setting in CPU for forcing compatibility mode. If that is not set, and you mvoe for example from AMD to Intel, then - this is not possible in live migration, cluster or not.

Comment: Yea the CPUs are compatible but at I can't seem to find any microsoft help regarding such Live Migration.. I know that there is one called "Copy Roles" on 2012 R2 but still this is now live since the VM needs to be shut down from the old cluster and turned on again on the new.. If you have any link providing help on such migrations I'd appreciate..

Comment: Yes, it's possible to live migrate Hyper-V machines between Hyper-V clusters from 2012 to 2012 R2. I've done it. The instructions for doing a live migration are the same as doing it with a single host. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134199.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need uncluster the VMs themselves before they can be migrated out of the cluster.  Use the Failover Cluster Manager to cause the cluster itself to stop protecting the VM.  Then you can migrate it using the Hyper-V Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically I managed to migrate VMs from a cluster to another cluster. These are the steps, First you have to remove the VM from the Failover Cluster Manager, this will still appear in the Hyper-V manager. Once it is no longer protected by Failover Cluster you can use the Move VM from the Hyper-V manager and move it to any host you want.